# How can a user choose items from a view?

Tags: 7, views, users

I've 3 types of users:

1. Author
2. Reader
3. Site Admin

**What I've done so far?:**

I've created Content Type named `Book`. `Authors`create account on my site & login & then add the information about the books they authored. I've a View with page-display named `books` which lists all the books.

**What do I need?**

1. `Reader` should be able to pick 'x' no. of books from the this view. The no. of books a `Reader` can pick depends on his level `Voracious Reader`, `Moderate Reader`, `Occasional Reader`.
2. After `Reader` choosing `Book(s)`, `Site Admin` will be see the list of books picked by all Readers.
3. He'll then ship  the book to their address (offline) & update the status as "Shipped".
4. of course Readers should be able to see the list of all the books they've chosen along with its status.

**How do I accomplish the rest?**

Comment: also see this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/104069/25307

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [flags module](https://drupal.org/project/flag) along with the default view it provides.

> Flags may be per-user, meaning that each user can mark an item
>   individually,

You can create two flags one called `Marked` and an other one called `Delivered`. Reader should be able to flag a Book as Marked but only Site Admin should be able to mark a Book as delivered.

If you are looking for more control consider using [Workflow](https://drupal.org/project/workflow) and then defining the states `Marked` and `Delivered`. You can set the access levels accordingly for the status change.